How to enable Inertia SSR on production?
I'm using Laravel Inertia with Vue.3 to build an SSR app.
My app is working well but the SSR is not working at all. When I disable javascript on my browser, I get a blank page.
I deployed my app on a simple VPS with nginx pointing to my public directory.
When i build my app i build the ssr file too and I'm using a supervisor to start the inertia server.
Here are my files :
Supervisor config
[program:inertia-ssr]
command=php /var/www/my-app/artisan inertia:start-ssr
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=5
numprocs=1
startsecs=0
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s_stderr.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s_stdout.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=10MB

app.js
import "./bootstrap";
import "../css/app.css";

import { createSSRApp, h } from "vue";
import { createInertiaApp } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import { resolvePageComponent } from "laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers";
import { ZiggyVue } from "../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy";

const appName = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME || "Laravel";

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) =>
        resolvePageComponent(
            `./Pages/${name}.vue`,
            import.meta.glob("./Pages/**/*.vue")
        ),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        return createSSRApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue)
            .mount(el);
    },
});

ssr.js
import { createSSRApp, h } from 'vue';
import { renderToString } from '@vue/server-renderer';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import createServer from '@inertiajs/vue3/server';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy';

const appName = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME || 'Laravel';

createServer((page) =>
    createInertiaApp({
        page,
        render: renderToString,
        title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
        resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
        setup({ App, props, plugin }) {
            return createSSRApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
                .use(plugin)
                .use(ZiggyVue, {
                    ...page.props.ziggy,
                    location: new URL(page.props.ziggy.url),
                });
        },
    })
);

vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            ssr: 'resources/js/ssr.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});

nginx config
server {
    server_name my-app.com www.my-app.com;
    root /var/www/savage-portfolio/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
     }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-app.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-app.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = my-app.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name my-app.com www.my-app.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

Did I misconfigured something or forgot a package in my application ?

Tip: if you need SSR, nuxt may be a good choice

@typed-sigterm Yes I know but now Inertia propose a SSR renderer and my app is already developed, I would like to use this one
